# Error when integrating Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to integrate Realm in my iOS app, so the data can be persistent.

Right now i'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Property 'sections' is declared as 'NSArray', which is not a
>   supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be primitives,
>   NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or
>   subclasses of RLMObject. See
>   https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html for more
>   information.' First throw call stack:...

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

The object class which is holding the `sections`.

```
class Workout: Object {
  dynamic var image: String = ""
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  dynamic var type: String = ""

  dynamic var sections:[String] = []

  var dayOne = List<Exercise>()
  var dayTwo = List<Exercise>()
  var dayThree = List<Exercise>()
  var dayFour = List<Exercise>()
  var dayFive = List<Exercise>()

  func addExerciseToSection(sectionName: String, exerciseName: Exercise) {
      if sectionName == "Day 1" {
        dayOne.append(exerciseName)
      } else if sectionName == "Day 2" {
        dayTwo.append(exerciseName)
      } else if sectionName == "Day 3" {
        dayThree.append(exerciseName)
      } else if sectionName == "Day 4" {
        dayFour.append(exerciseName)
      } else if sectionName == "Day 5" {
        dayFive.append(exerciseName)
      }
  }

  func getWorkoutInSection(workout: Workout, section: Int) -> List<Exercise>? {
      if section == 0 {
        return workout.dayOne
      } else if section == 1 {
        return workout.dayTwo
      } else if section == 2 {
        return workout.dayThree
      } else if section == 3 {
        return workout.dayFour
      } else if section == 4 {
        return workout.dayFive
      }
      return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error below just tell you that you can't assign certain types to Realm `Objects`, and specify the ones you can:

> All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber,
>   RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject.

Replacing this line:

```
dynamic var sections:[String] = []
```

might solve your error. Although, the issue is in the way you are constructing the data. Look at the [Sectioned tableView example](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#examples). The table view section can be created dynamically when loading the view, there is no need to save it to the realm object.

If you do want to save the `section` maybe consider using another realm object to do so, for example:

```
class Sections: Object{
    dynamic var section: String = "" 
}
```

Comment: I created another Realm object as you suggested, and now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

It clearly said that your property `dynamic var sections:[String] = []` is array and its not supported, you can try use `var sections = List<StringObject>()` where StringObject is Realm class contains your string

Comment: realm not allow using string in list

Comment: create an object that contains the string and use List

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to persist sections property you need to ignore it by

```swift
 override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["sections"]
  }
```

Comment: I need to persist every section, for each specific workout.

Comment: realm for now not supporting array of strings.If you don't want to bother with creating persistable String objects you need to merge whole string with separator keyword and split it with helper method to reach items.Saving this property as a NSData also another option.Sorry but neither of two options are less ugly